# KOMA-script titlepage misaligned author

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, koma-script

I'd like to set the titlepage of a koma-script `scrbook` left-aligned, i.e. `\raggedright`. I do this using `\addtokomafont` as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\addtokomafont{title}{\raggedright}
\addtokomafont{author}{\raggedright}
\addtokomafont{date}{\raggedright}

\title{My title}
\author{My name} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

However, what I get is an author name that seems to horizontally offset by about 0.2cm:

[image: Misaligned author name]

Any suggestions why this is and how I can avoid it? Of course, I could add a `\hspace{-0.2cm}` to `\author{}` but that feels like an ugly workaround.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how the `author` is typeset:

```
{\Large \lineskip 0.75em
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \@author
    \end{tabular}\par}
```

i.e., using a `tabular` and a `tabular` inserts `\tabcolsep`. You are seeing the `tabcolsep` on the left side. Making it zero like

```
\addtokomafont{author}{\raggedright\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}}
```

solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% just for demo

\addtokomafont{title}{\raggedright}
\addtokomafont{author}{\raggedright\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}}
\addtokomafont{date}{\raggedright}

\title{My title}
\author{My name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is much nicer than mine! :D

Comment: Many thanks! This way I also don't get the ugly "\hspace{-0.2cm}" in the pdf author tag generated by hyperref...

Comment: @Leo Glad it helped :-) BTW, welcome to the site. Have a nice time here :-)

Comment: @JuriRobl Being very simple though! :P